# Cakephp:Ajax generated textbox value are not submitting

Tags: cakephp

i am little bit new in cakephp, i am making a form for adding class and its section, for this one i have made a controller which code is such like that---
**addclasses_controller.php**

layout = 'internal';
         $session_id=$this->Session->read('User.id');
         $username = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' =>$session_id)));
         $this->set('session_id',$username);


         }


          function add()
          {
          $this->layout = 'internal';
           $session_id=$this->Session->read('User.id');
          $username = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' =>$session_id)));
          $this->set('session_id',$username);

             if (!empty($this->data)) {
             $this->Addclass->create();
             $this->red['Addclass']=array('classname'=>$this->data['Addclass']['classname'],'section'=>$this->data['Addclass']['section']);
             if(!!$this->Addclass->save($this->red)) {
             $lastid=$this->Addclass->id;

             $this->Session->setFlash('Categories is Saved!');
             $this->redirect(array('action'=>'add'),null, true);
             }
          }
          }

          function isAuthorized() {
            return true;
         }

        function addsection()
        {

         $noofsection=$this->data['Addclass']['section'];
         $this->set('noofsection',$noofsection);
        }


}

?>

and the add.ctp code is--

Add Class

 create('Addclass', array('url' => array('controller' => 'addclasses', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>
   
Class Nametext('classname',array('class' => 'users')); ?>
   
The Number of Section which you want to addtext('section',array('class' =>'users')); ?>
observeField( 'AddclassSection',array('url' => array( 'action' => 'addsection' ),'frequency' => 0.2,'onChange'=>true,'update'=>'employers'));?>
   

end('Submit');?>

and the model which i have used for this one---addclass.php

Section-" value="" class="users" name=""/>
 
    



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i am trying to access the ajax generrated text value in my add controller when the form is submiited, it access only those which is static in form , for checking this one i have debug($this->data);
i got only two value---
**`please help my problem , i really need this one in my cakephp project.`** 

?>

Comment: Can someone clean up the code at the bottom there?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the ajax helper in cake does not work well. I have replaced it to work with jQuery. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.loadsys.com/2009/05/01/cakephp-jquery-ajax-helper-easy-scriptaculous-replacement/).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with cdburgess - in my experience, the AJAX helper in CakePHP is intended for a very limited and (in my opinion) not very useful purpose - namely, clicking links and updating divs with the result.  I ended up using Prototype/Scriptaculous (which are better integrated with CakePHP than jQuery) to manually do AJAX, using Prototype's [AJAX functionality](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax) with CakePHP's [RequestHandler](http://book.cakephp.org/view/323/The-Request-Handler-Component) to determine when to return AJAX.

But if you're not doing much more than updating boxes, Reverse Folds has [a good article](http://www.reversefolds.com/articles/show/ajax) on using CakePHP's helper.